# A logon was attempted using explicit credentials. event ID 4648

Tags: networking, events, id

i am seeing this error on 3 pcs on the network and on our server, they are coming from 1 account that has been deleted and 2 that are still on the PC's. we are on a regular workgroup network with 2012 server std. we have Changed everybody's passwords recently. No services are using any accounts with passwords we changed. i am seeing this event log every 15 minutes. There are many task's but i dont see any with the user that has been deleted or other 2 users. This has been driving me crazy and i have to disable our account lockout policy since it is locking out 2 accounts on the server side....Any help would be great!?

A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x14CEB
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Account Whose Credentials Were Used:
    Account Name:       Melissa
    Account Domain:     MELISSA-PC
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Target Server:
    Target Server Name: SRV2008
    Additional Information: SRV2008

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x4
    Process Name:

Network Information:
    Network Address:    fe80::888:b5b0:27fb:13a0
    Port:           445

This event is generated when a process attempts to log on an account by explicitly specifying that account’s credentials.  This most commonly occurs in batch-type configurations such as scheduled tasks, or when using the RUNAS command.

Comment: I also checked the credential manager and no luck..

Comment: Remove **MELISSA-PC** from the workgroup

Comment: `i am seeing this error` - which error? Event 4648 is informational. If there is an event 4624 right after it, it means the logon attempt was successful. Otherwise you will see 4625.

Comment: Port 445 is most likely a hint that old credentials are cached somewhere on a network mapped drive.